# Выводятся все поля со всей таксономии в одном посте. WP + ACF

Tags: wordpress, acf

```
<?php

$args = array(
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'books',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => array($new_term)
        ),
    ),
    'post_type' => 'fairytale'
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( $query->have_posts() ) {

    while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
        $ID = get_the_ID();
        $song1 = get_field('book_song', $ID);
        $songname = get_field('book_song_name', $ID);
        $url = get_permalink($ID);
         ?>

            <audio class="player-f2" src="<?php echo $song1; ?>" type="audio/mp3" preload="auto" data-type="full" ontimeupdate='updateTrackTime(this);' data-name='<?php echo $songname ?>' data-url="<?php echo $url ?>"></audio>
        <?php 
    endwhile;
}

wp_reset_query();

?>
```

а в итоге выводятся все песни со всех постов этой таксономии

```
        <audio class="player-f2" src="http://site.ru/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/4-Страница-Бобр.mp3" type="audio/mp3" preload="auto" data-type="full" ontimeupdate='updateTrackTime(this);' data-name='Теремок' data-url="http://site.ru/fairytales/teremok/"></audio>

        <audio class="player-f2" src="http://site.ru/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/6-Страница-Бобр.mp3" type="audio/mp3" preload="auto" data-type="full" ontimeupdate='updateTrackTime(this);' data-name='Репка' data-url="http://site.ru/fairytales/repka/"></audio>

        <audio class="player-f2" src="http://site.ru/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/2-ctr.mp3" type="audio/mp3" preload="auto" data-type="full" ontimeupdate='updateTrackTime(this);' data-name='Колобок' data-url="http://site.ru/fairytales/kolobok/"></audio>
```

Comment: У вас цикл по всем постам таксономии, чего вы от него хотите?

Comment: @KAGGDesign это я в single.php пишу, как правильней будет только для этого поста?

Comment: Там вообще не нужен WP_Query, ядро все уже сделало. Смотрите иерархию шаблонов https://wp-kama.ru/id_7654/ierarhiya-fajlov-temy-shablona.html и стандартный цикл WP https://wp-kama.ru/id_767/3-sposoba-postroeniya-tsiklov-v-wordpress.html

Comment: @KAGGDesign делаю так <?php $myfile = get_field('file'); ?>

<a href="<?php echo $myfile['url']; ?>" >Download File</a>   соответственно все параметры ставлю, а он не выводит

Comment: Отредактируйте вопрос, приведите в нем полный код исправленного single.php